# Return ArrayList , Output in combination with get Methods

Tags: java, arraylist, getmethod

I thought this will work, but sadly it doesn't. I get the error-

> The method add(CustomerInfo) in the type ArrayList is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String)

My aim is to return an `Arraylist` and make an access with the get Methods. When I'm using String for the `Arraylist`, I can not use arr.get(i)**.userID**, ...**.FirstName** ...

**Class CustomerInfo.java**

```
  public class CustomerInfo {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static ResultSet resultSet = null;
    public String UserID;
    public String FirstName;
    public String SecondName;


    public ArrayList<CustomerInfo> findCustomer (String userID) throws SQLException {

            conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

            try {

                JDBCConnection jdbcConn = new JDBCConnection();
                conn = jdbcConn.openConnection();

                ArrayList<CustomerInfo> customerList  new ArrayList<CustomerInfo();

                String sql = "SELECT USERID FROM TAB0025 WHERE USERID = ?";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstmt.setString(1, userID);

                resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();


                while (resultSet.next()) {

                customerList.add(resultSet.getString("USERID"));
                customerList.add(resultSet.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
                customerList.add(resultSet.getString("SECONDNAME"));


                this.UserID = resultSet.getString("USERID");
                this.FirstName = resultSet.getString("FIRSTNAME");
                this.SecondName  resultSet.getString("SECONDNAME");

                }

                return customerList;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }

            finally {
                conn.close();
            }


        public String getUserID() {
            return this.UserID;
        }

        public String getFirstname() {
            return this.FirstName;

        }

        public String getSecondName() {
            return this.SecondName;

        }

    }
```

**Class InputReader.java**

```
    // ...

    if (CustomerInfo.ExsistUserID(this.UserID)) {

                    CustomerInfo edit = new CustomerInfo();
                    ArrayList<CustomerInfo> arr = new ArrayList<CustomerInfo>();

                    arr = edit.findCustomer(this.UserID);


                    System.out.println("UserID: "+ arr.get(0).getUserID() + "  First Name: "arr.get(0).getFirstName() + " Second Name: " arr.get(0).getSecondName()); 

                } 
   // ...
```

Comment: You have to be more specific about the piece of code which is giving you that error :)

Comment: What is "kundenList" mean here. where you declare.

Comment: @Jani sorry, that was a mistake, edited. But that's not the problem.

Comment: @Arkantos, the Output line is the problem.

Comment: @Panther.. have a look at Zlopez's answer. Issue is in while loop in `findCustomer` method not in output line as you mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in this three lines:

```
customerList.add(resultSet.getString("USERID"));
customerList.add(resultSet.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
customerList.add(resultSet.getString("SECONDNAME"));
```

As you can see above, `resultSet.getString()` method returns a `String` object but your ArrayList is container for objects of type `CustomerInfo`, so you need to create a new `CustomerInfo` object, populate its fields with the values from ResultSet and then add that object to your ArrayList like this:

```
custInfo = new CustomerInfo();
custInfo.UserID = resultSet.getString("USERID");
custInfo.FirstName = resultSet.getString("FIRSTNAME");
custInfo.SecondName = resultSet.getString("SECONDNAME");

customerList.add(custInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks, 0 Errors, finee ;-)

Comment: Also I suggest you move your `findCustomer()` to some other class. `CustomerInfo` is java bean to hold some state and any attempt to find an instance of that object should be outside that class, may be in some Service or DAO class